# How to make figure appear in foreground over header in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I'm making my first presentation in Beamer and I can't figure out how to make my company's logo appear on top of the header in the upper right corner of my slides. The logo appears in the correct spot but it's hiding under the header banner. My MWE for dummy image CompanyLogo.png:

```
\documentclass[11pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\graphicspath{{Images/}{./}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usefonttheme{default}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme{default}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}Company\hfill Proprietary\hfill\insertpagenumber}} %

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\logo{\hspace*{.8\paperwidth}\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{CompanyLogo.png}\vspace*{.8\paperheight}}

\title[Short Title]{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute[Company]{Company \\ \smallskip \textit{Email}}
\date[1/19/23]{January 19, 2023}

\sisetup{detect-all = true, detect-family = true}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
    \end{frame} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Presentation Overview}

    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections] 

\end{frame}

\section[S1]{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Frame 1} 

\end{frame}

\section[S1]{Section 2}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Frame 2} 

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge Thank You!}
        
        \bigskip\bigskip
        
        {\LARGE Questions? Comments?}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure that your logo is in front of everything else, you could add it to the footline template. That's the frontmost layer in a frame, see figure 1 from the beamer user guide

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\graphicspath{{Images/}{./}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
%
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usefonttheme{default}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme{default}
%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\smash{\hspace*{.8\paperwidth}\raisebox{.8\textheight}{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}}

\hspace{1cm}\parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}Company\hfill Proprietary\hfill\insertpagenumber}} %

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[Short Title]{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute[Company]{Company \\ \smallskip \textit{Email}}
\date[1/19/23]{January 19, 2023}

\sisetup{detect-all = true, detect-family = true}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
    \end{frame} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Presentation Overview}

    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections] 

\end{frame}

\section[S1]{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Frame 1} 

\end{frame}

\section[S1]{Section 2}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Frame 2} 

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge Thank You!}
        
        \bigskip\bigskip
        
        {\LARGE Questions? Comments?}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked thank you! Do you have a link to the resource you used? I haven't been able to find thorough documentation

Comment: If you open a command line and type "texdoc beamer" it should open the beamer user guide. In case you don't have the docs installed, you could also use https://texdoc.org/index.html or download the user guide from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer

Comment: When used this solution for the `Madrid` theme, all the footer disappeared!

Comment: @HoseinRahnama Please ask a new question including a compilable example which reproduces your problem.